# Alex CXD6 Wheelset Clincher or tubular?

Tags: wheels

The 2015 [Kona Jake the Snake](http://www.konaworld.com/jake_the_snake.cfm)e has Alex CXD6 wheelset installed, but i could not find any information is it for tubular, clincher or for both tire types ?

It has Challenge Grifo Comp 700x32c tires but apparently there are both tubular and clincher version of those available too.

Comment: I would say assume clincher but it is a CX.  You should include a link to the bike.

Answer (score 3):

That wheelset includes clincher-style rims that are tubeless compatible.

Be sure not to confuse tubular with tubeless. Tubeless looks similar to a clincher (beads on each side, open on the bottom), but doesn't use an inner tube, while tubular is a single whole tube with tire and inner tube combined; these tubular need to be glued on the rim.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are tubeless compatible clincher rims.

Comment: First time i have heard of such, i somehow thought that it's either clincher or tubeless. But this sounds good, if you can actually use both tubeless and clinchers with the same wheelset.

Comment: Most tubeless rims do both tubeless and clincher.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tubeless rim that can't take a clincher tire.

Answer (score 1):

The Alex CXD6 wheelset that is standard on that bike includes clincher rims, and are they are also tubeless ready.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.SE! Your answer has been flagged for review. This site doesn't work like a typical forum where each thread can include a wide range of information. It should instead be a Q/A format with each answer providing a clear answer to the original question. I've edited your answer for clarity and formatting. Please see the [Tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) for an overview of how this and other Stack Exchange sites work.

Answer (score -1):

100% Clincher. Nobody makes a production bike with tubulars - way too much of a liability issue. An improperly glued tire is extremely dangerous. Also gluing tubulars on is a very time consuming process which isn't possible in a mass manufacturing environment.

Comment: Looks like you have either mistyped, or have confused "Tubular" - a tire with the tube sewn into the tire and glued onto the rim; and "Tubeless". These wheels are tubless compatible clincher rims. You may want to edit or delete this answer to avoid downvotes.